# Why does artifact publish take a long time in Bamboo?

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

We are using Bamboo to build our code, create artifacts, and deploy.

#### Problem Scenario

I have a plan that has a stage with 3 jobs (dev/test/prod).  The jobs build the code and publish a 16-20Mb Artifact as a shared artifact.  When I run this plan, the publish takes 8-9 minutes for all 3 jobs.  The publish is happening at approximately the same timestamp for all 3 jobs.

Here is an example log statement:

```
simple  10-Sep-2021 13:46:15    Publishing an artifact: Preview Artifact
simple  10-Sep-2021 13:55:09    Finished publishing of artifact Required shared artifact: [Preview Artifact], pattern: [**/Artifact.*.zip] in 8.897 min
```

I went onto the build server (Windows Server 2012) and viewed the artifact file in the work directory and in the artifacts directory.  They are indeed almost 9 minutes apart with file timestamps.

This is very consistent.  I can view many previous builds and it is consistently taking 8 or 9 minutes.

#### Fixed Scenario

I just edited the plan and disabled 2 of the jobs.  Now the artifact publish step is taking a mere number of seconds:

```
27-Sep-2021 15:20:19    Publishing an artifact: Preview Artifact
27-Sep-2021 15:20:56    Finished publishing of artifact Required shared artifact: [Preview Artifact], pattern: [**/Artifact.*.zip] in 37.06 s
```

#### Questions

Why is the artifact publish so slow when I run concurrent jobs?  What is bamboo doing during the publish job step that could take so long?

I have 20 other build plans (that do not use concurrent jobs) in which the artifact copy takes less than a minute.  I have never seen this problem with any of these other plans.

I don't see anything special in [the documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/configuring-a-job-s-build-artifacts-289277071.html), nor can I find a problem like this when I search Google and Stack Overflow.  I need the artifact to be shared because I use it in a Deployment project.

**EDIT:**

Now that I think of it, 37 seconds is way too long as well.  I just copied the file manually and it took about a second.  Why is it taking so long even without concurrent jobs?

Comment: I wonder if the problem is something in the Bamboo database?

Comment: I just ran a verbose build with no additional information about this.

Comment: Only reason that comes to mind is a slow remote agent network. Artifacts are copied to remote agents prior to starting each job. That's why concurrent jobs require more copies since they are all launched on separate agents. However, 8 mins for 20MB makes me doubt this is the case.

Comment: We have 3 local agents and a disabled remote agent.  Server resources don't seem to be a problem; most of our builds take less than 2 minutes for build, unit test, and packaging.

Comment: We have upgraded Bamboo and now it is taking 2 seconds.

Comment: Nice! From which to which version?

Comment: Not sure what it was, but this is the version now: 8.1.1 build 80108 - 14 Dec 21 (Bamboo Data Center edition I believe)